# In python, why does select.select require that I sleep in a loop?

Tags: python, sockets, event-loop

I was writing a socket server. In the while loop,

```python
while True:
    rlist, wlist, _ = select.select([sock], [sock], [])

        for rsock in rlist:
            new_data = rsock.recv(RCV_SIZE)

        for wsock in wlist:
            wsock.send(other_data + TERMINATOR)

        time.sleep(0.1)
```

I noticed that when I exclude the time.sleep function, no data would come in. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you really need select() when you're only interested in one socket?

Comment: It doesn't. Is the socket nonblocking? Where does it get stuck? Probably in `send`

Comment: I suspect this gets stuck in `send` because it sends infinite amounts of data

Comment: @pingu yes you do, because reading is blocking, but with select, you convert the code into non-blocking.

Comment: @user253751 not quite, literally the difference between the code working and not working is the introduction of the time.sleep in there.

Comment: @possumkeys Agreed that it's non-blocking but without the sleep you'll just spin the CPU. That's rarely a good strategy

Comment: @possumkeys It is not converted to nonblocking. select returns if there's room in the buffer for even 1 byte, but send waits until it puts all of the bytes in the buffer

Comment: @DarkKnight noted. Good idea. But still... Why the difference? Does select need some time or something?